# Unable to use rxjs in the playcode code sandbox

Tags: rxjs

How to use rxjs in that application? I tried adding the lib but it doesn't work...

https://playcode.io/

Comment: Try StackBlitz RxJs starter project. https://stackblitz.com/fork/rxjs?devtoolsheight=60 StackBlitz is the bomb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next to libs push the + button and type rxjs. Then select rxjs.umd.js.

Now you can use rxjs like

```
const { Subject } = rxjs;

const subject$ = new Subject();

subject$.subscribe(val => { console.log(val); });

subject$.next('Hello world');
```

https://playcode.io/464609?tabs=script.js,preview,console

Same as using a snippet on StackOverflow but you can include the library from CloudFlare

```js
const { Subject } = rxjs;

const subject$ = new Subject();

subject$.subscribe(val => { console.log(val); });

subject$.next('Hello world');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

The key to using the umd library over the tree shakeable one is that all functionality is in one JS object/namespace. To use top level objects destructure them from the rxjs object

```
const { Subject } = rxjs;
```

instead of

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
```

and to use the operators destructure them from rxjs.operators like

```
const { map } = rxjs.operators;
```

instead of

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

But using StackBlitz is better as you can use the tree shakeable library https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-yyfxm9